# Bind a value to the data-placeholder attribute in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, angular6

How do I bind a value to the data-placeholder attribute on a div in Angular 6?

When I do the following:

`<div contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="{{placeholder}}">{{value}}</div>`

I get this error:

`Can't bind to 'data-placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `data-placeholder` is not known to Angular, you've to prefix it with `attr.`

example:

```
<div contenteditable="true" attr.data-placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
   {{value}}
</div>
```

or,

```
<div contenteditable="true" [attr.data-placeholder]="placeholder">
   {{value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer once the 10 minute count down is over. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see below code reference.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2y9vya?file=src/app/app.component.css)

You can implement in above way also.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="contentDiv" data-text="Enter text here"></div>
```

CSS File

```
[contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(data-text)
}

.contentDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[attr.data-placeholder]`

```
<div contenteditable="true" [attr.data-placeholder]="placeholder">{{value}}</div>
```